# Solution of system of inequalities in R

Tags: r

I have the following system of inequalities: Ay >= 0, where A is a 9x3 matrix, and `y = (y1, y2, y3)` is a vector of 3 elements. The solution of the inequality is a region, but I would like to return one possible tuple (y1, y2, y3) that would solve this inequality. Note that all elements of y have to be > 0.

Is there a way to do it in R?

Thanks

```
 A = matrix(runif(27, -0.5, 0.5), nc = 3)

 ### The system to solve is:    A %*% y >= as.matrix(rep(0,9))    Solve for y. Do not return region, but rather any possible tuple that solves the inequalities
```

Comment: `A %*% y ` is a vector. How are you determining " >0 "  ?

Comment: The problem with `optim` is that, since I do not know what the feasible region is, how can I provide starting values that fall in the feasible region?

Comment: @Carl Each row of A %*% y has to be greater than zero. I have adjusted the problem in the post.. The dimensions were also not correct, I have re-adjusted them as well..

Comment: `c(0, 0, 0)` is a solution to the problem stated in the question regardless of `A`.

Comment: I apologize, but I failed to specify that y > 0

Comment: Hmmm... 9 outputs but only 3 inputs. Something tells me there is no solution in general. Consider a matrix with rows (1,1,1), (1,1,-1),(1,-1,1), ... etc.  You may have to settle for maximizing the output, not forcing it to be >0

Comment: You could use linear programming.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Well, the problem with linear programming is that you have to provide a starting values of the parameters that fall in the feasible region. But since I don't know what the feasible region is (hence me trying to solve this problem), I can't specify valid starting values..

Comment: @Mariam There's no starting values to specify. But you have to specify a linear combination of `y` to be minimized or maximized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try linear programming:

```
library(Rglpk)
rhs <- rep(c(0, 1e-3), c(9, 3))
ge <- rep(">=", 12)

# an example with no feasible solution (status = 1)
set.seed(123)
A <- rbind(matrix(runif(27, -0.5, 0.5), nc = 3), diag(3))
Rglpk_solve_LP(obj = numeric(3), mat = A, dir = ge, rhs = rhs)

# an example with a feasible solution (status = 0)
A2 <- rbind(cbind(numeric(9), 1, -1), diag(3))
Rglpk_solve_LP(obj = numeric(3), mat = A2, dir = ge, rhs = rhs)
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you please tell me how to install this package?

Comment: `install.packages("Rglpk")`

Comment: I get the following message: Installing package(s) into ‘C:/Users’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

   package ‘Rglpk’ is available as a source package but not as a binary

Warning message:
package ‘Rglpk’ is not available (for R version 2.15.3)

Comment: Use the latest version of R.  Yours is years out of date.

Comment: I tried it, and I get a numerical solution. However, when I use that solution to compute A%*%y, the resulting vector doesn't have all positive elements!! I am not sure why!

Comment: Did `status` equal 1?  That indicates that no feasible solution was found so the contents of `solution` should be disregarded.

Comment: Yes indeed, status = 1. Does that mean there is no solution?

Comment: Right, there is no solution.  No feasible solution means that there is no solution that satisfies the constraints.  The first example of my answer illustrates that case and the second example illustrates the case where there is a solution.