# Solution region of a system of inequalities in R

Tags: r, linear-programming

I have a system of inequalities `Ab >= 0`, where `A` is a `n by p` matrix, `b` and `0` are vectors of length `p` and `n`, respectively. Is there a package or function in R that would return the solution region? Or something like the upper and lower limits for each entry in `b`?

I've checked out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24432059/solution-of-system-of-inequalities-in-r), but the solution in the answer only seems to return a `p`-tuple solution for `b`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Or something like the upper and lower limits for each entry in b?"

This can be done by solving 2p LPs:

```
for i in 1:p do
   solve LP: min b[i] subject to Ab >= 0
   solve LP: max b[i] subject to Ab >= 0
```

Comment: Thanks. Which package should I use? And could you provide a short code example?

Comment: This approach is independent of the LP solver. The implementation of course is not.

Comment: Which package or function in R would you recommend for the implementation? Would `lpSolveAPI` work.

Comment: Depends on many things like the size of the problem, how complex the model is, how important speed and robustness are, etc.

Comment: Could you tell me a couple of packages so I can look into them? My original question was asking about R packages and functions.

Comment: Many LP packages are listed here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html

Comment: I don't think the solution you've added as your answer works for my problem. I've included a toy example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65973520/how-to-solve-the-following-linear-programming-problem-to-minimize-multiple-varia

Comment: The min value of x1 and the minimum value of x2 are not part of the same solution. These are different solutions.

Comment: Would it be possible to minimize both x1 AND x2? That's what I was getting at with the "solution region". Maybe I was unclear.

Comment: "something like the upper and lower limits for each entry in b" was the question I answered. The feasible region is not a box, in general. I suggest to read a book about linear programming.

Comment: Sure. Can you point me to some resources for this specific problem? Where I want to minimize x1 AND x2.

Comment: Read about multi-objective optimization and what optimality means in that context. That will keep you busy for a while.